# Suggestions for an Algorithm to retrace steps history?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

1. Can anyone suggest a good data structure to store steps history taken  by a single insect in a simulation in Java?

I am writing an algorithm that searches for an item within a grid. The insect moves from point A until it finds what its looking for (point B). The insect needs to now go from Point B back to point A by retracing its steps.

2. Can anybody suggest a way of accomplishing this?

I have about 6 months of Java/programming experience and I'm working on a class project so I appreciate any suggestions or guidance that I can get.

Comment: Does the insect retrace its former steps in exactly the reverse order, or does it follow a more optimal path in reverse that eliminates unnecessary branching deviations in the path, e.g.?

Comment: How about a `List` of whatever a "step" looks like, e.g. the x,y of the location, or the up/down/left/right direction?

Comment: @Ike *"**retracing** its steps"* would indicate reverse the path taken, i.e. follow the breadcrumbs back.

Comment: @Andreas Yeah, I just wanted to make sure there's no optimization of the reverse path. For example, if the insect was wandering around a maze the whole time and ran into all kinds of dead-ends along the way, if it would redundantly go back to all the former dead-ends while wandering about, or a more optimal path back to home base.

Comment: @Andreas If so, it becomes kind of tied more to graph theory. If not, a simple contiguous structure based on an array (like `List`) makes the most sense... in a grid setting, it might even suffice to store a single index per step (easy to deduce x/y from the cell index).

Comment: You can use DFS or BFS to do this....You want to do backtracking i guess....and BFS and DFS are best solution for it...There are many ways to that also either using Stack(DFS) or queue(BFS),  or using recursion.
Hopefully it helps

Comment: For simplest solutions, stack would be perfect for this case, you can just pop each value and output it. Although there would be some additional logic required when you would find a better path. Or use some implementation of list and iterate it in reverse when outputting the answer.

Comment: @Ike it retraces the same steps

Comment: Thank you guys! This helps a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data-structure that you need is called [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29), it implements LIFO (last in - first out) principle. There is a [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) class in java.

Some additional info: `Stack`'s methods are synchronized, which adds some performance overhead, and in software development [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is usually picked instead. Anyway considering that this is a class assignment - pick any implementation you like.

Comment: Mentioning synchronized and performance overhead to someone who has 6 months of experience and working on a class assignment, really?

Comment: @MarkoGrešak, why not? I wrote that this is an "additional info".

Comment: Because it's unnecessary information and adds to confusion. Sure, it's useful in practice, but you know the saying "You have to learn to walk before you can run".

Comment: I must admit that I thought the question had something more to do with it, like performance unless there was something fancier going on with the retracing of steps (ex: retracing a more optimal or more "frequently-traveled" path back home), since a stack is such a simple data structure to implement with anything that provides a back insertion and removal. I thought there had to be something more there with respect to the question, whether it was algorithmic or performance-related.

Comment: @user3707125 thank you for the information. I was thinking Stack but I wasn't sure. :)

Comment: You mention `Stack` (with link) and then talk about how it being synchronized is an issue and suggest `LinkedList` instead. Why not follow suggestion listed in the linked javadoc? *"A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class."*

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for that.

If `x` and `y` are coordinates at any instance....

For going from Point A to Point B:

```
#loop till insect reaches point B{
    String coords = x + "," + y;
    someArrayList.add(coords);
    #insect move;
}
```

For going Back to Point A:

```
for(int i =0; i < someArrayList.size(); i++)
    String x = someArrayList.get(i);
    String[] y = x.split(","); // To separate x and y coordinates from string
    #insect move to coordinate (y[0], y[1]);
```

Hope this helps as a hint (since I dont know what method you use to make your insect move and other details).

Comment: I find your code rather confusing, `someArrayList.add(x,y)` may lead to usage of [this method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29), instead of [the one you actually mean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29). And you didn't explain why `someArrayList` will contain `String`s instead of coordinates. I mean I do understand what you did, but it may cause a lot of misunderstanding for someone inexperienced.